# prove $ 1 < \varphi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} < 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, golden-ratio

Prove $ 1 < \varphi =  \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} < 2$

Just want to see if my "reasoning is sound.

1) Showing $1 < \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$

Consider $\frac{1}{2}$:

$$\frac{1}{2} < \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} < \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} $$

2) Showing $\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} < 2$

We know $$\sqrt{5} < 3 \\ \Rightarrow 1 + \sqrt{5} < 4 \\ \Rightarrow \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} < 2$$

Therefore: $ 1 < \varphi =  \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} < 2$

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is sound.  It might be easier to start with $1<5<9$.

Comment: looks okay; consider being more explicit about how we know $1<\sqrt5<3$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, how would I go about that?. That is exactly the thing I'm trying to work on....

Comment: is it possible to squaring positive numbers  1<$\sqrt5$<3 ? and 1<5<9?

Comment: note for $x>0$, $f(x)=\sqrt x$ (and its inverse) is increasing

Comment: Your $\frac12<\frac12+\frac12$ is redundant. Better is $1=\frac12+\frac12<\ldots$

Comment: Well, I'd ask how do you know $\sqrt{5} > 1$? or how do we know $\sqrt{5} < 3$?   It seems to me this is punting the question.

Comment: I agree with your take @fleablood, I was trying to understand what J.W. Tanner was getting at with his statement, but it doesn't lead me anywhere.

Comment: Or... how about this.  Punch it into a calculator and you get $1.6180339887498948482045868343656$.  Is that any less legitimate?  Okay... that was tongue in cheek but it seems the most straightforward is $n^2 < 5 < (n+1)^2$ is only if $4 < 5 < 9$ so $2 < \sqrt 5 < 3$ the rest is just manipulation.

Comment: After readint lab bhattacharjee's answer I imagine we are supposed to you $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}2$ to do this (that'd just be a matter of punching numbers into a caluculator) but that *definition* of $\phi$ in a positive number where $\phi = 1 + \frac 1\phi$.

Comment: I am given what $\varphi$ is equal to, but I was not given that $\varphi = 1 + \frac{1}{\varphi}$, I don't think the intention of thequestion is to use a calculator to justify the inequality. Your solution seems appropriate @fleablood

Comment: Well, it's fine but $2 < \sqrt 5  < 4$ is the basis to calculate it.  The rest is mechanical. But the reason $\frac {1+\sqrt 5}2$ is interesting but something lik $\frac {2 +\sqrt 7}3$ is not, is that the neat thing about $\phi$ and *why* it is called "the golden ratio" is that: Then amount by which $\phi$ is more than $1$ is proportional to $1$ by the same amount $1$ is proportional to $\phi$.  That is $\frac {\phi -1}1 = \frac 1{\phi}$.  If we solve we get $\phi^2 -\phi - 1=0$ or $\phi =\frac{1+\sqrt 5}2$.

Comment: In other words if you have a rectangle with sides $x,y$, $x>y$ and if you remove the $y\times y$ square you get a rectangle with sides $y-x$ and $x$.  If the big rectangles proportion $\frac yx$ is equal to the small rectangles proportion $\frac x{y-x}$ so $\frac yx = \frac x{y-x} =\phi$ we call that proportion $\phi$.  If we replace $y$ with $\phi\cdot x$ we get $\frac yx = \frac {\phi\cdot x}x = \phi$ and that is equal to $\frac x{\phi x -x}=\frac 1{\phi -1}$.  So $\phi = \frac 1{\phi -1}$ and $\frac 1\phi =\phi-1$ so $\phi = 1+\frac 1\phi = \frac 1{\phi - 1}$.

Comment: And if we solve $\phi = 1+\frac 1\phi = \frac 1{\phi -1}$ we get $\phi^2 - \phi=1$ so $4\phi^2 - 4\phi = 4$ and so $4\phi^2 - 4\phi + 1 = 5$ and $4<(2\phi -1)^2 = 5<9$ and $2< 2\phi -1=\sqrt 5<3$ so $3<2\phi =1+\sqrt 5 < 4$ and $\frac 32 < \phi=\frac {1+\sqrt 5}2 < 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

$4 < 5 < 9$

$2< \sqrt 5 < 3$

$3 < 1 + \sqrt{5} < 4$

$\frac 32 < \frac {1+\sqrt{5}}2 < 2$.

$1 < \frac 32 < \frac{1+\sqrt{5}} 2 < 2$.

.....

I suppose maybe a more direct way of solving would be

$n < \frac {1+\sqrt 5}2 < n+1 \iff$

$2n < 1+\sqrt 5 < 2n + 2\iff$

$2n-1 < \sqrt 5 < 2n+1 \iff$

$(2n-1)^2 < 5 < (2n+1)^2$.

So our task is to:  Find to consecutive odd numbers so that $5$ is between the squares.  Those odd numbers are $1$ and $1^2 < 5$ and $3$ and $3^2 > 5$ and so $2n -1 = 1$ and $2n+1 = 3$

And so $n =1$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

As $\varphi>0,$

$\varphi=1+\dfrac1{\varphi}>1$

$\implies1+\dfrac1{\varphi}<1+1$

Comment: I can fill in the blanks here, but it *looks like* you're saying $a>1\implies a < 2$

Comment: @David, as $\varphi>1,$ $$\dfrac1{\varphi}<1$$ right?

Comment: Yes, but (in my opinion) it leaves a lot of thought to the OP. If this were an assignment, I feel a grader would read that and not believe the student understands why that implication holds.

Comment: An answer to such a question here should leave some thought to the OP, shouldn't it?

Comment: I like this as $\phi$ is *defined* as the positive value so that $\phi = 1 +\frac 1\phi$.  That $\phi = \frac {1+\sqrt 5}2$ is calculation.  Figuring the value if $\frac {1+\sqrt 5}2$ isn't something to... prove.  It's just a calculation.